# Issue for closed testing google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

why is the test link closed when accessed The application is not available The test version of this application has not been published or is not available for this account.
[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ05t.png)
[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B42EF.png)

What I tried:

Clicked on the closed testing link: I received the link from the developer of the app and tapped on it to access the test version.
Logged in with my Google account: I was prompted to sign in with the account that was supposedly included in the closed testing group.
What I expected:

App download or Play Store page: I anticipated either being directed to the app's download page in the Play Store or a specific page within the Play Store with instructions on how to install the test version.
What actually happened:

Error message: Instead of the expected outcome, I encountered an error message stating, "App not available. A testing version of this app hasn't been published yet or isn't available for this account."
Additional details:

I'm unable to determine precisely why the link isn't working.
I've contacted the developer for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The developer has to add your gmail account as an approved tester in the Google Play Developer Console before the link will work for you.